# Every connected graph of order at least two contains 2 vertices that can be deleted without disconnecting graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am working on the following problem:

Let G be a connected graph of order at least two. Show that there are two vertices $u$ and $v$ such that both G - $u$ and G - $y$ are connected.

My thoughts:

Since G is connected, we know that it contains a spanning tree. We can clearly delete a leaf of this spanning tree and G will remain connected. I am pretty sure that if $|G| > 2$, then the spanning tree of G must contain two leaves that we can delete (w/o affecting connectivity, of course), but I am not sure how to formally prove this.

Comment: Consider the end vertices of the longest path in the tree.

Comment: All trees with at least two nodes contain at least two leaves, yea.

Comment: Here is a proof of a tree having two leaves: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306226/prove-every-tree-with-at-least-1-edge-has-2-leaves